# Как получить ссылку на последнюю страницу блога WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть следующий код, который по-идее должен возвращать ссылку на последнюю страницу блога, однако он выводит ссылку на главную страницу блога со всеми записями, то есть по факту на первую страницу. Что не так в данном коде??

```php
function get_last_page_url($wp_query = null) {
    if (!$wp_query) {
        global $wp_query;
    }

    $max = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $link = esc_url(get_pagenum_link($max));

    return $link;
}
```

Comment: где вызываете функцию?

Comment: пробовала даже просто в functions.php через echo вызвать и передаю в функцию параметр $wp_query, но с ним и без него все равно ссылку на первую страницу выдает

Comment: 1.get_pagenum_link возвращает ссылку относительно той странице в которой вы его вызываете. 2.Вы скорей всего передаете глобальный $wp_query, а не свой.Вам изначально дали вредный совет с создание своего wp_query, щас будете мучатся с этим.

Comment: Поняла, а как же тогда получить ссылку на последнюю страницу в блоге, не подскажите?

Comment: Где нужно выводить ссылку? На той-же странице блога или на разных страницах?

Comment: вообще на разных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function get_last_page_url() {

    //$published_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
    $published_posts = count( get_posts( array('posts_per_page' => -1,'category' => '-7',) ) );
    $posts_per_page = 2; // число на стр
    $page_number_max = ceil($published_posts / $posts_per_page);

    //$link = esc_url(get_pagenum_link($page_number_max));
    $link  = get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ) . 'paged/' . $page_number_max;

    return $link;
}
```

Получаете все посты, делите на постов на стр, получаете число страниц.

Далее получаете линк на страницу блога.

Если нужно получить все посты, то тогда используйте `wp_count_posts()`, если нужно исключить категорию то оставьте вариант с `get_posts`.

Comment: Работает, идеально) и последний вопрос, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть такой кусок кода, не пойму как здесь правильнее вызвать данную функцию

```php
```

Comment: ```php
add_filter('navigation_markup_template', 'my_navigation_template', 10, 2 );

function my_navigation_template( $template, $class ){
 return
  '<div class="col-md-12">
   <nav class="navigation %1$s box-pagination text-center" role="navigation">
    <div class="blog-pagination nav-links">
     <li class="first arrow"><a href="http://wpdev/blog/page/1">first</a></li>
     %3$s
     <li class="last arrow"><a href="<?php get_last_page_url(); ?>">last</a></li>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>';
}
```

Comment: Вы ее и так вызываете, когда срабатывает фильтр

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду мне ее надо вызвать в этой строке, где адрес, но из-за return весь код читается как текст

```php
<li class="last arrow"><a href="<?php get_last_page_url(); ?>">last</a></li>
```

Comment: из-за кавычем, используйте конкатенацию строк или делайте через `ob_start()`